# Find the walking speed of his wife given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Anwar leaves everyday at 4pm to pick his wife from office and returns home at 6pm with the same route without any stoppage .One day the office was over at 4pm and his wife started walking home from office. Anwar unaware of this starts from home as usual and meets his wife on the way and returns home with his wife 15 minutes early.if the speed of Anwar's car is 30 kmph,find the walking speed of his wife.

options:

a) 30/7 kmph

b) 3.6 kmph

c) 34/5 kmph

d) 5.4 kmph

MyApproach:

I did t1+t2=2 hrs

=> D1/$30$ + D1/$30$=$2$    ...eq1

=>$2$D1/$30$=$2$=>D1=$30$

$30$/$30$ + D2/Speed of wife=1:45 minutes  ...2

$1$ + D2/Speed of wife=$7$/$4$

D2/Speed of wife=$3$/$4$

I can only form these $2$ equations only.But,I am nowhere getting to the results.

> Can Anyone guide me how to solve the problem after this?Or any other approach through which I get Ans?

Comment: Hint: Determine the time which Anwar meets his wife. Since the car travels at a constant velocity, it takes the same amount of time to go and come back.

Comment: @Element118 I think I did exactly same for 1st equation.

Comment: Can you define your variables $D_1$, $D_2$, $t_1$ and $t_2$?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 6 year old question but I'm answering this for anyone who (like me) needs a solution. @Element118's hint in the comments was the thing that I was missing and you might be too, so please read the hint and try again. If you still don't get it, below is the solution.

Solution:

Let the distance between his house and his wife's office be x km.
Then, 2x = 30 km/h * 2hrs = 60 km
=> x = 30 km

Let his wife's speed be w km/h.
Then their relative speed = 30+w km/h

Therefore, the time they take to meet each other on the way = 30 km/(30 km/h + w km/h) ------(1)

The time required to turn back and return home will also be the same as in equation (1). (Refer to @Element118 's comment with a hint on the post above for the reasoning)

Thus, 2*30/(30+w) = 2hours - (1/4)hour [Since it is given that he reaches home 15 mins, i.e., 1/4 hour earlier]

Solving the above equation gives w = (30/7) km/h, i.e., option a.